# How to access request data in Nested Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create writable nested serializer to create posts. I want to create multiple model instances of Image and Video. However, I don't know how to access `request.data` in the nested serializer which is necessary for the `many=True` condition

```
#serializers.py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    images = ImageViewSerializer(many=True)
    videos = VideoViewSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['caption', 'user', 'images', 'videos']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'caption': {'required': False},
            'images': {'required': False},
            'videos': {'required': False}
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

I want to make it like so...

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    images = ImageViewSerializer(many=isinstance(request.data,list))
    videos = VideoViewSerializer(many=isinstance(request.data,list))
    
    ...
```

Update:

I don't know if its the best practice but here is how I am creating the post now.

```
#serializers.py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['caption', 'user']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {'required': True},
            'caption': {'required': False}
        }

    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        image_data = self.initial_data.get('photos')
        video_data = self.initial_data.get('videos')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        caption = validated_data.pop('caption', None)

        if image_data is not None and isinstance(image_data, list):
            images = [Image(post=post, images=photo) for photo in image_data]
            Image.objects.bulk_create(images)
        elif image_data is not None and  isinstance(image_data, str):
            Image.objects.create(post=post, images=image_data)

        if video_data is not None and isinstance(video_data, list):
            videos = [Video(post=post, videos=video) for video in video_data]
            Video.objects.bulk_create(videos)
        elif video_data is not None and  isinstance(video_data, str):
            Video.objects.create(post=post, videos=video_data)

        Tag.objects.extract_hashtags(post, caption)
        
        return post
```

Comment: Override `__init__` method like this: `def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs)` and then inside of it `self.image = ImageViewSerializer(many=isinstance(kwargs.get('request').data,list))` also define both as None like `images = None`

Comment: please share code related to PostSerializer